# In this example, why is it still necessary to typecast an object to be sure of its type, even after getClass() has been called?

Tags: java, casting

I'm following [this MOOC on OOP in Java](http://mooc.fi/courses/2013/programming-part-2/) and it has presented [an example I don't fully understand](http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part2/material/week-8?noredirect=1).  In the example, a `Book` class has been created and they are constructing an 'equals' override method for the `Book` class.  The new `equals()` method takes a parameter of any object.  It returns true if that parameter is a `Book` object with the same name and publishingYear as this `Book` object.  Because the parameter object could be any object of the Object class, before calling the `getPublishingYear()` and `getName()` methods, which would throw an error if called on an object not in the `Book` class, the `equals()` method checks to make sure it is indeed dealing with a `Book` object through this code:

```
 if (getClass() != object.getClass()) {
        return false;
 }
```

This much (I think) I understand.  What I don't understand is why, after the code above, they then cast the parameter object into a `Book` and then call `getPublishingYear()` and `getName()` on the newly casted object instead of the original:

```
Book compared = (Book) object;

if (this.publishingYear != compared.getPublishingYear()) {
    return false;
}

if (this.name == null || !this.name.equals(compared.getName())) {
    return false;
}

    return true;
```

I don't get why this step is necessary when the method should already have returned false if the object was not of type Book due to the `getClass()` check above.  I tried compiling without this extra casting step and found that the step is indeed necessary - the compiler gives a 'cannot find symbol' error on `getPublishingYear()` and `getName()` if you do not include this step.  So what am I missing?

The `equals()` method in full:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println(getClass());
    if (getClass() != object.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Book compared = (Book) object;

    if (this.publishingYear != compared.getPublishingYear()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.name == null || !this.name.equals(compared.getName())) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The Java compiler does not infer this by itself. You still have to do the casting. Your IDE is probably clever enough to auto-complete Book methods on `object` after that `if`, but the compiler has to follow the language spec to the letter (and that does not include this kind of type inference).

Comment: You're missing the point that you can only do things with an object that is known to the compiler according to the *declared* type of the variable, not the *actual* type. That is because Java is a strictly-typed language. Loosely-typed languages, like Groovy, will allow calls to methods on the actual type, but it comes at the cost of deferring type-checking until runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a variable to a data type basically is telling the compiler "Trust me, I know what I'm doing." In the case of casting an "Object" to "Book", you are assuring the compiler that the object is, in fact, a Book and to proceed accordingly. It also as the effect of forcing you to believe you know what you are doing.

Edit: I'm not sure if you are asking why you needed the actual cast (adding "(Book)") or why you needed to make the assignment to a Book variable. I answered the former. If the question is the latter, the answer is you need the Book variable so the Book methods are available.

Since you have the tools to make the determination, you would think that the cast is not necessary since the compiler is capable of generating the same code you use to make the determination, requiring you to just make the assignment:

```
Book book = object;           // Wrong
```

instead of

```
Book book = (Book) object;    // Right
```

If you expect the compiler to "just know" that the Object is a Book, then the compiler will have to test the Object each time you use a Book method. By explicitly telling it in the assignment, the compiler can create code specific to the Book class without any further examination of the Object.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler cannot (is forbidden to)  infer that your previous type check was done for the purpose of eliminating improper object types before casting.
E.g., sometimes less is more: what if in the next statements you only need to cast your object to one of the base classes or implemented interfaces?

```
interface Authored {
  public getAuthorName();
}

interface Publication {
  public String getISBN();
};

public class Book
implements Authored, Publication {

// ...
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    // on purpose, we use only the Publication interface
    // because we want to avoid potential misspelling or missing 
    // title, author name, etc. impacting on equality check
    // We'll consider ISBN as a key unique enough to
    // determine if two books (e.g. registered in different 
    // libraries) are the same
    Publication p=(Publication)other;
    return this.getISBN().equals(p.getISBN());
  }
}
```

Comment: I concur with "forbidden" rather than "cannot". However, there seems to be a trend towards the compiler making more type inferences than in the past. In Java 8, I can write "HashMap<String, SomeClass> map = new HashMap<>();" and the compiler infers "String, SomeClass" in the RHS. I'd guess someday the compiler will infer the cast based on the type of the LHS in such assignments as the OP has asked -- depending on, of course, who is determining the direction Java takes. It seems redundant to me to have to specify "Publication" on both sides of "=".

Comment: @user3481644 took some decade or so for C++ to adopt the `auto` type specifier for a LHS, I wouldn't bet Oracle being nimbler.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast your `Object`-type object to `Book`, because you want to use `getPublishingYear()` and `getName()` functions which are specific to the `Book` class. The `Object` class does not have such methods.

Answer (score 1):

after

```
if (getClass() != object.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

you can be sure your object is a book, but java still does not know it

so you can savely tell it to try the casting with

```
Book compared = (Book) object;
```